# ClickOnce deployment from a network share and parameters

Tags: clickonce

Is it possible to pass command line parameters to a ClickOnce application deployed from a network share? I would like to be able to run the application with command like this:

\\server\share\MyApp.application -parameter1 test -parameter2 value2

For some reason the ActivationUri is allways null.

If I deploy the application to IIS and run it like in the example below it works fine.

http://intranet/apps/MyApp.application?parameter1=test&parameter2=value2

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give more information to your specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, you can't do this. In order to use the query parameter option with ClickOnce, you have to deploy your application to a web server, and it must be set as "online only".